# Achieve Import statement linting/show/highlight warning(s) in vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Previously i was working with pycharm. I would like to move my javascript development to vscode. Am having a project which uses nexj.js (react SSR) and am having problem with imports statements/declarations. I would like to configure vscode to throw warning or highlight/report import statements that have:

1. Unresolved file references imports in JavaScript files
2. Checks whether the module in require or import statement exists or is installed, if it dosen't exist throw a warning.

Check my code:

```
import React from 'react' # this is installed, okay
import PropTypes from 'prop-types' # this is installed, okay
import Head from 'next/head' # this is installed, okay

import { getDataFromTree } from 'react-apollo' # this does not exist yet no warning shown
import cookie from 'cookie' # this does not exist yet no warning shown

import lodash from 'west/you/kkhdh/jjjjds' # this does not exist yet no warning shown
import initApollo from './kkk/kkkfkfkf' # this does not exist yet no warning shown
```

Comment: Well, one way would be to add eslint to your project, which has a rule import/no-unresolved set up. Having linter in project is always a good idea anyways

Comment: I have tried several blogs i.e. [this](https://medium.com/innow8/react-react-native-configure-eslint-airbnb-prettier-and-precommit-with-husky-in-one-go-for-code-e89363e5f17f). None seems to work.